# ThreadPoolTaskScheduler how to async every future

Tags: java, spring

autowired threadpooltaskschedule:

```
@Autowired
private ThreadPoolTaskScheduler threadPoolTaskScheduler;
@Bean
public ThreadPoolTaskScheduler threadPoolTaskScheduler() {
    threadPoolTaskScheduler = new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();
    threadPoolTaskScheduler.setPoolSize(10);
    return threadPoolTaskScheduler;
}
```

future test:

```
public void test(){
    ScheduledFuture future = threadPoolTaskScheduler.schedule(new MyFuture(), new CronTrigger("0/5 * * * * ?"));
}
private class MyFuture implements Runnable{
    @Override
    public void run() {
       int a=0;
       for(int i=0;i<1000000;i++){
          for(int j=0;j<1000000;j++){
              a++;
          }
       }
    }
}
```

When I run `test()`, I found that the first thread is running but time over 5s, second thread is not running and waiting for first thread to complete. Now how to let thread async to execute and don`t wait last thread complete?
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaDoc for `CronTrigger` says the following

```
/**
 * Determine the next execution time according to the given trigger context.
 * <p>Next execution times are calculated based on the
 * {@linkplain TriggerContext#lastCompletionTime completion time} of the
 * previous execution; therefore, overlapping executions won't occur.
 */
```

So **therefore, overlapping executions won't occur**.
You need to do some workarounds if you really need overlapping tasks.